# What are the limitaions and inabilities while using HTML5 in android? And what are the advantages using HTML5 in android?

Tags: android, html

What are the limitaions and inabilities while using HTML5 in android?  And what are the advantages using HTML5 in android?

I have researched the web for a while, but i cant get any answers about HTML5 in android development. Is everyone prefer to develop HTML5 web apps in Android. If yes give some advantages,limitations,inabilities with the combination.

If i started with HTML5 web app in Android what are the features i cant use from native android.

Please help me to provide some suggestions or direct me to an useful link...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google io had a prrsentation on it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4f2Zky_YyyQ&noredirect=1.

Comment: The above link doesnt direct me to the Google IO presentation...

Comment: Yes it is goes to the presentation. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest advantage of HTML 5 in my opinion is te independency of platform and the huge compatiblity when rendering xml-based formats like SVG.
However, HTML5 apps will never have the robust strength of a native app.
I found that combining HTML(in a webview) with the standard Android Java environment works really well. By implementing a javascript interface, which is really easy to do, you can communicate between your HTML content and your native android app. 
This way you can use the compatibility advantages of HTML together with the power and features of a native android app.