# Javascript -- push audio to mobile device (Mobile Safari and Chrome)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, audio, web-audio-api

I've written up some javascript that successfully pulls and plays audio files on the desktop. However, I just can not get this figured out on a mobile device -- which really is my intent.

Right now for the desktop, I can push and play audio with this javascript:

```
 var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
 audioElement.setAttribute('src', url);             
 audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
 $.get();
 audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
    audioElement.play();
    }, true);
```

(where url is a location on my web server)

I've read that audio on mobile requires an initial user action to activate, so I then tried making:

```
 var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
```

A global element, and then in the document.ready section, I activated the audio when the user presses a 'tool' button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#toolButton").click( function () {
    // Need a 'click' event to turn on sound for mobile devices
    if (audio_init === undefined) {
        audioElement.play();
    }
    audio_init = 1;
```

However, this was not successful.

I then tried web audio, again, this code allows me to play on a desktop browser, but nothing on mobile:

```
var webaudio_play = function(url) {
    ctx = new webkitAudioContext(); 
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET",url,true);
    req.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    req.onload = function() {
        ctx.decodeAudioData(req.response, function(buffer) {
        var src = ctx.createBufferSource(); 
        src.buffer = buffer;
        src.connect(ctx.destination);
        //src.start();
        src.noteOn(0);
        });
    };
req.send();
}
```

I really have no idea where to go next. Has anyone succeeded in pushing and playing an audio file to a mobile device?

Comment: Well, you seem to have tried everything. Any error? have you checked that the code is executed? does it just fail silently?

Comment: It just fails silently. I haven't hooked up a tablet so I can debug via desktop chrome or safari yet.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this answer for status:

[What are the limitations of HTML5 audio on Android and iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603605/what-are-the-limitations-of-html5-audio-on-android-and-ios)

There are some mobile limitations.

Comment: Interesting. Aware of the limitations, however that hpr.dogphilosophy.net/test/ site plays wav files on both Android Chrome and IOS Safari, when the 'load this file' button is pressed.

Comment: @HP1, steal that code and compare it with yours! :)